# Shadow Nanoflex pickup not working anymore

Tags: pick-ups, pre-amp

I have an electroacoustic folk guitar (Lâg 4 seasons) equipped with a **Shadow preamp**, and a **Shadow nanoflex pickup**.

During the past few days, I have been experiencing very annoying noises which, according to me, were due to a contact failure. While inspecting the guitar, and testing it all around, the issue seemed to be linked to the wire connecting the Nanoflex to the preamp.

[image]

To my surprise, the end of the connector can be taken to pieces by unscrewing it.

[image]

However, after I unscrewed it, and screwed it back again, **the preamp is not receiving sound anymore**. I really don't understand why this is happening, since I only unscrewed the end of it, and srewed it back.

Is it possible that unscrewing it broke the soldering inside ?

Note : I'm 99.9% sure the preamp is working properly, because if I plug it into a guitar amp, and I touch the pickup input with my finger, it buzzes.

Comment: This isn't something easily diagnosed over the internet. Take it to a repair shop.

Comment: @Tetsujin - true, but one of our many contributors may have had the same problem.

Comment: @Tim - indeed, true. However, if you're going to unscrew a jack plug by twisting the plug not the barrel... then any next step ought to be taken by someone who wouldn't do that - ie a professional ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a type of mini jack plug.  The idea is that you unscrew the cover and push it back along the cable, revealing the soldered connection.    However, you have left the cover attached to the cable and unscrewed the plug off it, and off the cable.

It can be repaired.  But the cable looks flimsy, and I suspect it will be moulded into the pickup, not easy to completely replace if you mess up.  Take it to an expert in such things.

Comment: Thank you for the pointer. The thing is that when I first took the mini jack plug out of the guitar's body, it was already mid-unscrewed, and wobbly, which could totally be the cause of the noises I had. Anyways, a brand new nanoflex pickup costs about 45€, and that will be a thousand times less expensive than bringing the guitar to a repair shop.

Comment: Guess you might as well attempt a repair yourself  then!

Comment: If I manage to get a new nanoflex, this won't be repairing at all, since I'll only have to plug the pickup in the preamp, I'll try not to screw this one up (no pun intended).